# Error parsing config overrides - `nlp.tokenizer` sections does not exist

Tags: spacy

I encountered a weird problem in Spacy and I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong or it is a genuine bug.

I use Spacy project and create a default config file via:

```
python -m spacy init config spacy.cfg
```

Then I try to load an NLP object using this config:

```
import spacy
config = spacy.util.load_config('./spacy.cfg')
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", config=config)
```

When do this I get the following error:

```
ConfigValidationError: 

Error parsing config overrides

nlp -> tokenizer -> @tokenizers   not a section value that can be overwritten
```

By looking at what is going on inside through PDB I noticed that section `nlp.tokenizer` is not created. Instead the config stores the following ugly item within the NLP section:

```
'tokenizer': '{"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}'
```

which does not seem to look allright.

I am using Spacy v3.0.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that tokenizer setting. `en_core_web_sm` already contains its own config including a tokenizer, which is what you can't override.

You want to load your config starting from a blank pipeline instead of a pretrained pipeline:

```py
nlp = spacy.blank("en", config=config)
```

Be aware that the language `en` needs to match here with the `spacy init config` language setting or it won't be able to load the config.

Comment: Thanks! So a quick follow up question, because now I am confused about possible usages of Spacy projects. Can I use a config file to modify a pretrained model such as en_core_web_sm to modify it, for instance by adding additional pipeline components? So `spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")` would load the model with additional pipes? Or this can be done only by writing explicit Python code in an application?

Comment: You can write a config or do it programmatically, but the key is using the `source` option: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#sourced-components